# Use'data-confirm-modal'on rails6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-6

### 【want to】

I want to introduce data-confirm-modal in rails6 and create the following modal.
[image]

#### version

ruby 2.7.1p83
Rails 6.0.3.5

### 【Current status】

As you can see, the default modal has come out.
[image]

### 【Steps tried】

#### 1.Described in gemfile

```
gem 'data-confirm-modal'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.4.1'
```

#### 2.Execute bundle install

#### 3.Add to application.js

app/javascript/packs/application.js

```
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.

require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")


// Uncomment to copy all static images under ../images to the output folder and reference
// them with the image_pack_tag helper in views (e.g <%= image_pack_tag 'rails.png' %>)
// or the `imagePath` JavaScript helper below.
//
// const images = require.context('../images', true)
// const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)
//= require data-confirm-modal ←Add this
```

#### 4.Restart the rails app

```
bundle exec rails s
```

#### ５.Modify view

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', "/competitions/#{@competition.id}", method: :delete, data:
          { confirm: '本当に削除して良いですか?',
            cancel: 'やめる',
            commit: '削除する'}, title: '削除確認' %>
```

#### ６.result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Webpacker, you don't need to install the gem.

1. Remove the `data-confirm-modal` gem from your `Gemfile`
2. Install jQuery, bootstrap, and data-confirm-modal via yarn - `yarn add jquery popper.js bootstrap@3 data-confirm-modal` (`popper.js` is a bootstrap 3 dependency)
3. Set up Webpack to automatically load jQuery in `config/webpack/environment.js`

```js
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')

environment.plugins.prepend(
  'Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    jQuery: 'jquery',
  })
)

module.exports = environment
```

4. Require `popper.js`, `bootstrap`, and `data-confirm-modal` in `app/javascript/packs/application.js`. Make sure `data-confirm-modal` is required after `require('@rails/ujs').start()`

```js
require('popper.js')
require('bootstrap')
require('@rails/ujs').start()
require('data-confirm-modal')
// other require statements
```

Comment: thanks for teaching me! I proceeded according to this site.[link](https://github.com/ifad/data-confirm-modal) If I write this in the view, nothing is displayed.` <%= link_to 'Delete', data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>`

Comment: Please let me know if you like

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing is displayed"? What happens when you click on the link? Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: Nothing happens when I click the link.
The URL looks like this. http://localhost:3000/competitions/6/edit?data%5Bconfirm%5D=Are+you+sure%3F

Comment: @katahik Can you provide a minimal reproducible example app to debug?

Comment: [bitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/katahik/workout-competition/src/d5f595f9802a100b41b989e9a8c33fc7386ebda8/?at=feature%2FWC-5-%E5%A4%A7%E4%BC%9A%E3%81%AE%E6%A6%82%E5%BF%B5-%E5%A4%A7%E4%BC%9A%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90)

Comment: @katahik You haven't installed jQuery and Bootstrap via yarn. I've updated my answer with the required steps.

Comment: thanks you. The modal came out .
Please tell me two points at the end. 1.Do I have to write what I installed via yarn in application.js? 2. Is the code written in environment.js necessary when using jQuery with webpack?